# Use font attachment from an mkv container when burning hard subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I want to use the font that is in an mkv as an attachment when I burn in subtitles.

I found a way to do this using `-dump_attachment` first.

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i video.mkv
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf "subtitles=video.mkv:stream_index=0:fontsdir=." video.mp4
```

This has to be a common use case. Is there one ffmpeg command that can do these two steps?

Comment: Are you sure that executing `ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i video.mkv` before the next command in your post, changes the content of `video.mp4`? (compared to executing the command `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf "subtitles=video.mkv:stream_index=0:fontsdir=." video.mp4` without executing `ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i video.mkv` command before it). I think the output of `-dump_attachment:t ""` is a `.ttf` file, but you are not using the dumpet `.ttf` file it in the second command...